# Is a plain question mark in GET request valid?

Tags: apache, get-request

Is a plain question mark in GET request valid?

So, this is an example:

```
GET ? HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Apache responds with the homepage:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
```

Other servers seem to throw a 400 Bad Request.

Which is the proper response? Apache or others?

Answer (score 0):

RFCs 2616 (HTTP 1.1) and 3986 (HTTP 2.0) don't have much to say about the exact format of a query string. According to RFC 3986,

> The query component contains non-hierarchical data...
> The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4

So, syntactically, a bare question mark at the end of a URL is acceptable, if useless, and the Apache implementation is correct.

Comment: So, if there is not a slash in the GET request, it is valid? Right.